external-secrets-provider-aws is not authorized to perform secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
I have external-secrets operator installed and trying make it work with a SecretStore for retrieve AWS parameter store.
My aws secret manager resides in my app's aws account and I am using ESO from Openshift (AWS) configuring cross account IRSA. So I created a role secret role with the below
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
        "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:123456789:secret:*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I have attached this role with the Service Account.
If I try to create a external-secret for AWS secrets, with a new SecretStore, the SecretStore' status is Valid but the ExternalSecret that references this SecretStore got the following error: SecretSyncedError

AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/secret-role-pre/external-secrets-provider-aws is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: dev/testkey because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action status code: 400,

Though we don't have any such role external-secrets-provider-aws but not sure from where this is coming.
can you please help to identify the issue and make it work ?
